# send many NSURLConnection requests and get response in connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: iphone, json, ipad, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to send many asynchronous request to php file that shows my data as json code and in the response I parse the json so I added the following in ViewDidload:

```
NSURLRequest *aboutRequest = [self getDataFromServer:@"http://al-awal.com/Rashad/iPhonePhp/about.php"];
aboutConn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:aboutRequest delegate:self];


NSURLRequest *wisdomRequest = [self getDataFromServer:@"http://al-awal.com/Rashad/iPhonePhp/wisdomtoday.php"];
wisdomConn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:wisdomRequest delegate:self];
```

then

```
-(NSURLRequest *) getDataFromServer:(NSString *)phpUrl{
responseData = [NSMutableData data];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phpUrl]];

return request;
}
```

then I added:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([[rashadDB databasePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        if (connection == aboutConn) {
            NSLog(@"get from table about");
            SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

            NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

            for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
            {

                NSString *sAboutID = [status objectForKey:@"ID"];
                NSString *sPhone1 = [status objectForKey:@"Phone1"];
                NSString *sPhone2 = [status objectForKey:@"Phone2"];
                NSString *sJawal = [status objectForKey:@"Jawal"];
                NSString *sFax = [status objectForKey:@"Fax"];
                NSString *sWebSite = [status objectForKey:@"WebSite"];
                NSString *sEmail = [status objectForKey:@"Email"];
                NSString *sAddress = [status objectForKey:@"Address"];

                int sAboutID2 = [sAboutID intValue];

                NSLog(@"in server, aboutID = %d, Phone1 = %@, Phone2 = %@, Jawal = %@, Fax = %@, WebSite = %@, Email  = %@, Address = %@",sAboutID2, sPhone1, sPhone2, sJawal, sFax, sWebSite, sEmail, sAddress);

                sqlite3_exec(database, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR ABORT INTO About VALUES(%d, '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@')",sAboutID2, sPhone1, sPhone2, sJawal, sFax, sWebSite, sEmail, sAddress] UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);

                sqlite3_exec(database, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE About set Phone1 = '%@', Phone2 = '%@', Jawal = '%@', Fax = '%@', WebSite = '%@', Email  = '%@', Address = '%@' Where aboutID = %d", sPhone1, sPhone2, sJawal, sFax, sWebSite, sEmail, sAddress, sAboutID2] UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);

      }  

            } else if (connection == wisdomConn) {
                NSLog(@"get from table wisdoms");

                SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

                NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

                for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
                {
                    NSString *sWisdomTodayID = [status objectForKey:@"ID"];
                    NSString *sContent = [status objectForKey:@"Content"];
                    NSString *sAuthorName = [status objectForKey:@"AuthorName"];
                    NSString *sDateCreate = [status objectForKey:@"DateCreate"];
                    NSString *sEnable = [status objectForKey:@"Enable"];


                    int sWisdomTodayID2 = [sWisdomTodayID intValue];
                    int sEnable2 = [sEnable intValue];

                    NSLog(@"wisdomTodayID = %@, Content = '%@', AuthorName = '%@', DateCreate = '%@', Enable = %@", sWisdomTodayID, sContent, sAuthorName, sDateCreate, sEnable);

                    sqlite3_exec(database, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR ABORT INTO WisdomToday VALUES(%d, '%@', '%@', '%@', %d)",sWisdomTodayID2, sContent, sAuthorName, sDateCreate, sEnable2] UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);

                    sqlite3_exec(database, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE WisdomToday set Content = '%@', AuthorName = '%@', DateCreate = '%@', Enable = %d  Where wisdomTodayID = %d", sContent, sAuthorName, sDateCreate, sEnable2, sWisdomTodayID2] UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);

                }


            }


        } // sqlite3 open end

        sqlite3_close(database);

    }
```

the first if condition --> if(connection == aboutConn)  works ok with me and I got my output but the other if condition --> if (connection == wisdomConn) only gives me this output  NSLog(@"get from table wisdoms");  and not go throw the for loop.
Is there are any wrong in my code?

Comment: Is this the real code? It seems that the curly braces aren't properly balanced. So this wouldn't compile.

Comment: ok I edited it, it is real code.

Comment: I've edited the code and properly indented it. It's now pretty obvious that the *if* for the second connection is within the *if* for the first connection where it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 3):

You are not closing braces properly...

Before opening the brace for else - if condition you should close the brace for if_condition..

Comment: sorry the wrong of brace is in this post but it is ok in my xcode. the problem is not from braces anyway. I edited it

Comment: @user1553381: Either the problem is the nesting of the braces, or you are wasting our time with code different from the real one.

Comment: No, I'm not target to waste anyone's time. ok thanks for the editing. is the problem now clear? I'm not got my answer till now

Answer (score 0):

Some of your relevant code is missing (the `NSConnectionDataDelegate` methods).  But it would seem that you are using one instance variable, `responseData`, to build up both return values.  This would mean that some times you would get the faster response data only; and other times you would get mixed data in the same `NSMutableData` object.

Comment: sorry, I'm not got your mean. could you show a sample code for me please?